# Is Euclidean division unique in an ED

Tags: ring-theory

Re-reading an algebra course I was wondering about something.

Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain endowed with a Euclidean function $f$, *ie*  a function satisfying :

- $f(a) \leq f(ab) \, \,\forall \, a, b \in R\backslash\{0\}$
- $\forall \, (a,b) \in R\times R\backslash\{0\} : \, \exists \, q,r \in R, a = bq + r$ with either $r = 0$ or $f(r) < f(b)$

The latter axiom being Euclidean division (I know the first one is not 100% necessary but that's not my point here).

What I'm wondering is whether this Euclidean division is unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (with the complex modulus) two possible divisions of $1+i$ by $2$: $1+i=2*0+(1+i)$, $1+i=2*1+(i-1)$.

I can’t find a reference, but I remember reading that every Euclidean domain where the Euclidean division is unique is either a polynomial ring in one variable over a field or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What's the definition of $f$ here?

Comment: $f(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$.

Comment: So the quared norm.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, thanks :). While I'm at it, if I may ask, there is something else bothering me. I see somewhere that (with the above definition), in a Euclidean domain, $f(ab) = f(a) \iff b$ is a unit. And while the proposition "$b$ is a unit $\implies f(ab) = f(a)$" is quite easy to prove, I can't see a way to prove the converse. Is it actually true? :)

Comment: Assume $f(ab)=f(a)$, then there is some $k,r$ such that $a=k(ab)+r$ and $r =0$ or $f(r) < f(a)$. Now, $a|r$ so the second possibility doesn’t occur. So $a=kab$ thus $kb=1$.